# Nginx development machine setup

Tags: nginx

I am trying to setup my windows development machine with nginx and I would like to be able to run multiple sites. What I tried to do is assign different ip addresses for each domain in nginx.conf and hosts files as below:

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    gzip on;
    server_tokens off;
    add_header X-Frame-Options Deny;
    expires 365d;

    include       mime.types;

    server {
        listen 172.76.0.10:80;
        server_name  mywebsite.local;
        root   /Websites/mywebsite_dev;

        location / {
            index  index.php;
        }       

        location ~ \.php {  
                include fastcgi.conf;       
                fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000; 
        }  
    }

    server {
        listen 172.76.0.11:80;
        server_name  mywebsite-two.local;
        root   /Websites/mywebsite-two_dev;

        location / {
            index  index.php;
        }       

        location ~ \.php {  
                include fastcgi.conf;       
                fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000; 
        }  
    }
}
```

hosts

```
172.76.0.10    mywebsite.local
172.76.0.11    mywebsite-two.local
```

But when I try to run the nginx service I get this error:

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 172.76.0.10:80 failed (10049: FormatMessage() error:(15100))
```

Anyone has an idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is it your computer ip?

Comment: Hi, no its just an unused IP. I'm new to nginx but I dont think I could set all server blocks to listen to 127.0.0.1 (localhost).

Comment: You have to bind to your existing ip. If you want different IPs, you could use 127.0.0.2, 127.0.0.3 and so on.

Comment: But binding all server blocks to the same IP is perfectly valid and is the usual setup.

Comment: Tnks! using the 127.0.0.* range worked perfectly.